# plotting exponential and polynomial function together in python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, polynomials, exponential

I want to plot the following y and y' functions together on the same axes in python. The x-axis values should go from -10 to 10 in 0.1 intervals:
[image]

what I tried:
I tried plotting just y' (labelled y_p) and I am getting errors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10,10,0.1)

A=1
B=0.1
C=0.1
y_p = (A*np.exp((-x**2)/2))(1+(B*((2*(np.sqrt(2))*(x**3))-(3*(np.sqrt(2))*x))/((np.sqrt(6)))))
plt.plot(x,y_p)
```

but this generates error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-c184f15d17c7> in <module>
      7 B=0.1
      8 C=0.1
----> 9 y_p = (A*np.exp((-x**2)/2))(1+(B*((2*(np.sqrt(2))*(x**3))-(3*(np.sqrt(2))*x))/((np.sqrt(6)))))
     10 plt.plot(x,y_p)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

​
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. I'm quite new to python, so any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: `^` applies a binary operation. To use the power function, the synthax is `**`. Example x²: `x**2`

Comment: thanks @Julien..i have corrected that bit now but still getting error in calling the y_p function..please check my edit in my post

Comment: you have a missing  `*` sign in `y_p`, right before  `(1+B*...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot multiply implicitly (without using `*`) in python.

Here is your code after the correction:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)

A = 1
B = 0.1
C = 0.1
y_p = (A * np.exp((-x ** 2) / 2)) * (1 + (B * ((2 * (np.sqrt(2)) * (x ** 3)) - (3 * (np.sqrt(2)) * x)) / (np.sqrt(6))))
plt.plot(x, y_p)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate approach would be to take it a step at a time:

You could start by defining `y1` as a lambda:

```
y1 = lambda x: (2*np.sqrt(2)*x**3 - 3*np.sqrt(2)*x)/np.sqrt(6)
```

Then implement your formula:

```
y_p = A * np.exp(-x**2/2)*(1 + B*y1(x))
```

This way you have less chances of getting a typo.

Comment: Prettier answer than mine